# Можно, ли перевести String в код java

Tags: java, python, exec

В Python есть метод exec(), есть ли такое в Java?

Comment: если захотеть, [можно аналог Python `eval()` написать](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runtime_evaluation/In_an_environment#Java), но скорее всего для решения конкретной задачи можно лучше подходы найти (иначе говоря [это XY-проблема скорее всего](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044))

Answer (score 2):

Нет, python интерпретируемый язык программирования, в отличае от java. Инными словами для того, чтобы запусить код java, его вначале нужно скомпилировать.

Comment: А позвольте поинтересоваться, что мешает exec'у скомпилировать код на лету? Тем более питоновый exec именно этим и занимается (интерпретируется байткод, а не исходник).

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса непонятно зачем работать с java в режиме интерпретации.

Почитайте про [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). В определенных случаях это может помочь.